# .Net Entity Framework in a Single Page Application Saving Changes to Model

Tags: .net, entity-framework-core, blazor-webassembly

I am using a .Net SPA (Blazor WASM) with Entity Framework. In addition, I am using Temporal tables as well. The issue I am having is that when the user is editing a model, if they are adding/deleting child models, I get unexpected results when the model saves.  For example, if I am editing the base model, and add new child models, and then add new child models to the child models, not all the models will be saved correctly.  Am I constructing this correctly?  Here is my code:

**Entity Framework Models:**

```
    //Unity Item can have 0, 1, or more UnityModels.  These models are simplified and have extra properties removed.

    public class EFModelUnityItem : BaseModel<EFModelUnityItem>
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Required] public string UnityItemName { get; set; } = string.Empty;
        public string GeneratedGuid { get; set; } = string.Empty;       
        public ICollection<EFThreeDimensionalModel>? UnityModels { get; set; }
    }
    
    //EFThreeDimensionalModel can have 0, 1, or more Child3DModels.  But, a child will never have children.
    //if the EFThreeDimensionalModel is a child, it will have a Parent
    //EFThreeDimensionalModel can also have 0, 1, or more ModelFiles
    
    public class EFThreeDimensionalModel : BaseModel<EFThreeDimensionalModel>
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string ModelName { get; set; } = string.Empty;
        public string GeneratedGuid { get; set; } = string.Empty;           
        public EFModelUnityItem UnityItem { get; set; }
        public int UnityItemId { get; set; }
        public int? ParentModelId { get; set; }
        public EFThreeDimensionalModel? ParentThreeDimensionalModel { get; set; }
        public ICollection<EFThreeDimensionalModel>? Child3DModels { get; set; }      
        public ICollection<UnityItemModelFiles>? ModelFiles { get; set; }
    }
    
     public class UnityItemModelFiles : BaseModel<UnityItemModelFiles>
     {
         public int Id { get; set; }
         public string GeneratedGuid { get; set; } = string.Empty;
         public string ModelFileType { get; set; } = string.Empty; //is Material, Texture or Object file
         public string FileName { get; set; } = string.Empty;
         public string FileType { get; set; } = string.Empty;     
         public string FileExtention { get; set; } = string.Empty;
         public EFThreeDimensionalModel? EFThreeDimensionalModel { get; set; }
         public int? EFThreeDimensionalModelId { get; set; }
     }
     //Entity relationships 

     modelBuilder.Entity<EFThreeDimensionalModel>()
      .HasMany(d => d.ModelFiles)
      .WithOne(d => d.EFThreeDimensionalModel)
      .HasForeignKey(d => d.EFThreeDimensionalModelId).OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);

    modelBuilder.Entity<EFThreeDimensionalModel>()
    .HasMany(p => p.Child3DModels)
    .WithOne(p => p.ParentThreeDimensionalModel)
    .HasForeignKey(p => p.ParentModelId);
    
    //database is temporal.  so, when an update is made, the old record is moved to the History table and the new record is added.
    //this is all done by MS SQL
     modelBuilder.Entity<EFModelUnityItem>().ToTable("EFModelUnityItem", c => c.IsTemporal());      
     modelBuilder.Entity<EFThreeDimensionalModel>().ToTable("EFThreeDimensionalModels", c => c.IsTemporal());   
     modelBuilder.Entity<UnityItemModelFiles>().ToTable("UnityItemModelFiles", c => c.IsTemporal());
```

**DTO Models:**

```
    public class UnityItemDTO : BaseModel<UnityItemDTO>
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Required] public string UnityItemName { get; set; } = string.Empty;
        public string GeneratedGuid { get; set; } = string.Empty;   
        //  The entity table allows for a one to many, but DTO is one to one            
        public UnityItem3DModelsDTO? unityItemModel { get; set; }          
    }
    
    public class UnityItem3DModelsDTO : BaseModel<UnityItem3DModelsDTO>
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string ModelName { get; set; } = string.Empty;
        public string GeneratedGuid { get; set; } = string.Empty;           
        public int UnityItemId { get; set; }
        public int? ParentModelId { get; set; }
        //EF model groups all three files into one list: public ICollection<UnityItemModelFiles>? ModelFiles { get; set; }
        //but in the DTO, we split them out into three files.  if UnityFileDTO.ModelFileType = "OBJECT"
        public UnityFileDTO? ObjectBrowserFile { get; set; } // if UnityFileDTO.ModelFileType = "OBJECT"
        public UnityFileDTO? MaterialBrowserFile { get; set; } // if UnityFileDTO.ModelFileType = "MATERIAL"
        public UnityFileDTO? TextureBrowserFile { get; set; } // if UnityFileDTO.ModelFileType = "TEXTURE"
        public string? FileName { get; set; }
        public List<UnityItem3DModelsDTO> AccessoryModels { get; set; } = new List<UnityItem3DModelsDTO>();  
    }
    public class UnityFileDTO: BaseModel<UnityFileDTO>
    {           
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string GeneratedGuid { get; set; } = string.Empty;
        public string ModelFileType { get; set; } = string.Empty; //is Material, Texture or Object file
        public string FileName { get; set; } = string.Empty;            
        public string FileExtention { get;set; } = string.Empty;
        public int? EFThreeDimensionalModelId { get; set; }
    }
    
    
    The problem with the code is that when I add multiple new UnityModels, with associated new ModelFiles, then remove the files,
    it will cause unexpected results when the whole model is saved.  It will delete the wrong models.
```

**Example Code:**

```
    //this code is called when the user saves changes to an existing UnityItemDTO.  Because this is a Single Page App, the user, in the same context, may have added new AccessoryModels and/or UnityFileDTO, or they may have deleted AccessoryModels or UnityFileDTO, or they may have updated data in UnityFileDTO or AccessoryModels
    
    public async Task<ServiceResponse<UnityItemDTO>> UpdateUnityItem(UnityItemDTO unityItem)
    {
        try
        {
            if (unityItem.Id < 1)
                return new ServiceResponse<UnityItemDTO> { Data = null, Message = "Unity Item ID Missing", Success = false };
            
            //Gets the EF model based on ID
            var foundUnityItem = await GetUnityItemByIdAsync(unityItem.Id);

            if (foundUnityItem == null)
                return new ServiceResponse<UnityItemDTO> { Data = null, Message = "Unity Item Not Found", Success = false };              

            if (unityItem.unityItemModel != null)
            {
                await UpdateunityItem3DModels(foundUnityItem, unityItem.unityItemModel, null);
            }              

            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

            //need to update the child components that were recently added, with their new Id's so it can be sent back to the UI with any updated ID'same
            //This will convert the EF Model to DTO Model
            var newunityItem = await ConvertUnityItemModelToDTO(foundUnityItem);

            return new ServiceResponse<UnityItemDTO> { Message = "Unity Item Updated!", Success = true, Data = newUnityItem };
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return new ServiceResponse<UnityItemDTO> { Data = null, Message = $"Error updating unity item: {ex.Message}", Success = false };
        }
    }
    
    
    private async Task UpdateUnityItem3DModels(EFModelUnityItem unityItem, UnityItem3DModelsDTO unityItemModel, EFThreeDimensionalModel parentModel)
    {            
        if (unityItemModel == null)
            return;

        try
        {
            var existingModel = unityItem.UnityModels!.FirstOrDefault(m => m.Id == unityItemModel.Id);

            if (existingModel != null)
            {         
                //its an updated  model
                
                existingModel.GeneratedGuid = string.IsNullOrEmpty(unityItemModel.GeneratedGuid) ? Guid.NewGuid().ToString() : unityItemModel.GeneratedGuid;
                existingModel.ModelName = unityItemModel.ModelName;
                existingModel.ParentModelId = unityItemModel.ParentModelId;                   

                var listOfFiles = new List<KeyValuePair<string, UnityFileDTO>>();
                //since EF model is a one-to-many, just add all the files to one list
                if (unityItemModel.MaterialBrowserFile != null)
                {
                    listOfFiles.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, UnityFileDTO>("MATERIAL", unityItemModel.MaterialBrowserFile));
                }
                if (unityItemModel.ObjectBrowserFile != null)
                {
                    listOfFiles.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, UnityFileDTO>("MODEL", unityItemModel.ObjectBrowserFile));
                }
                if (unityItemModel.TextureBrowserFile != null)
                {
                    listOfFiles.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, UnityFileDTO>("TEXTURE", unityItemModel.TextureBrowserFile));
                }
                await UpdateModelFiles(unityItemModel, existingModel, listOfFiles);

                foreach (var childModel in unityItemModel.AccessoryModels)
                {
                    await UpdateunityItem3DModels(unityItem, childModel, existingModel);
                }

            }
            else
            {
                //its a new model
                var newModel = new EFThreeDimensionalModel
                {
                    ModelName = unityItemModel.ModelName,
                    UnityItem = unityItem,                       
                    GeneratedGuid = string.IsNullOrEmpty(unityItemModel.GeneratedGuid) ? Guid.NewGuid().ToString() : unityItemModel.GeneratedGuid,
                    ParentModelId = unityItemModel.ParentModelId,
                    ParentThreeDimensionalModel = parentModel
                };
     
                var listOfFiles = new List<KeyValuePair<string, UnityFileDTO>>();
                if (unityItemModel.MaterialBrowserFile != null)
                {
                    listOfFiles.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, UnityFileDTO>("MATERIAL", unityItemModel.MaterialBrowserFile));
                }
                if (unityItemModel.ObjectBrowserFile != null)
                {
                    listOfFiles.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, UnityFileDTO>("MODEL", unityItemModel.ObjectBrowserFile));
                }
                if (unityItemModel.TextureBrowserFile != null)
                {
                    listOfFiles.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, UnityFileDTO>("TEXTURE", unityItemModel.TextureBrowserFile));
                }
                await UpdateModelFiles(unityItemModel, newModel, listOfFiles);


                if (parentModel != null)
                {
                    parentModel.Child3DModels ??= new List<EFThreeDimensionalModel>();
                    parentModel.Child3DModels.Add(newModel);
                }

            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
        
    }
  //add/delete/update all the models associated files.
    private async Task UpdateModelFiles(UnityItem3DModelsDTO unityItemModel, EFThreeDimensionalModel model, List<KeyValuePair<string, UnityFileDTO>> newFiles)
    {
        try
        {
            if (newFiles != null && newFiles.Any())
            {
                if (model.ModelFiles == null)
                {
                    model.ModelFiles = new List<UnityItemModelFiles>();
                }

                var existingIds = model.ModelFiles.Select(b => b.Id).ToList();

                var filesToRemove = model.ModelFiles
                    .Where(item => !newFiles.Any(pair => pair.Value.Id == item.Id))
                    .ToList();

                foreach (var item in filesToRemove)
                {
                    model.ModelFiles.Remove(item); 
                }         
                foreach (var itemDTO in newFiles)
                {
                    if (itemDTO.Value.Id == 0)
                    {
                        //new file
                        var fileEntity = new UnityItemModelFiles
                        {                        
                            FileName = itemDTO.Value.FileName,
                            EFThreeDimensionalModel = model,
                            FileExtention = itemDTO.Value.FileExtention,                                
                            GeneratedGuid = string.IsNullOrEmpty(itemDTO.Value.GeneratedGuid) ? Guid.NewGuid().ToString() : itemDTO.Value.GeneratedGuid,
                            ModelFileType = itemDTO.Key.ToUpper()                                
                        };                           
                        model.ModelFiles.Add(fileEntity);
                        _context.UnityItemModelFiles.Add(fileEntity);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        // Update existing battery
                        if (model.ModelFiles.Any())
                        {
                            var existingItem = model.ModelFiles.Where(x => x.GeneratedGuid == itemDTO.Value.GeneratedGuid).First();
                            if (existingItem != null)
                            {
                                existingItem.FileName = itemDTO.Value.FileName;
                                existingItem.FileExtention = itemDTO.Value.FileExtention; 
                                existingItem.ModelFileType = itemDTO.Value.ModelFileType; 
                                existingItem.GeneratedGuid = string.IsNullOrEmpty(itemDTO.Value.GeneratedGuid) ? Guid.NewGuid().ToString() : itemDTO.Value.GeneratedGuid;         
                            }
                        }                            
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                //its an empty list, so delete everything
                if (model.ModelFiles != null)
                {
                    foreach (var existingFile in model.ModelFiles.ToList())
                    {
                        _context.UnityItemModelFiles.Remove(existingFile); // Remove from context
                        model.ModelFiles.Remove(existingFile); // Remove from collection
                    }
                }                  
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }            
    }
```

Comment: Please reduce the code to the essentials.

Comment: Yes, I appreciate that sentiment @GertArnold but I am not sure where the logic error is that is causing the issue.  I removed as much of the extraneous code as possible.  If the models are not helpful, I can remove them?